# Froala insert link creates duplicate text

Tags: javascript, froala

I am facing issue with froala editor, i am using version 2.9.2
Double click to Select a text and press CTRL + K , this opens a insert link window with URL and TEXT input fields, the TEXT input box is already populated with the text you selected previously, you enter the URL and click insert, a link is created and the selected text is duplicated, ideally the previously selected text should have got converted to a link

Answer (score 0):

Update at least to 2.9.5. The issue seems to be fixed.